# neo4j SDN @Index annotation mixes domain objects

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a class EntityNode defined like below

```
@NodeEntity
@TypeAlias("Entity")
public class EntityNode {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @Indexed(indexName="entity_name_ft", indexType=IndexType.FULLTEXT)
    private String name;
```

also I have many other domain objects annotated with @NodeEntity and @TypeAlias(...) (@TypeAlias("Document"), @TypeAlias("UrlVisit") etc...)

After inserting some data and I run this query:

```
start n=node:entity_name_ft('*:*') return n.name, n.type, labels(n);
```

i also get nodes that are NOT of type EntityNode but are returned by the index 'entity_name_ft':

```
==> | <null>                                | <null>               | ["__TYPE__UrlVisit","UrlVisit"]                 |
==> | <null>                                | <null>               | ["File","__TYPE__File"]                         |
==> | <null>                                | <null>               | ["__TYPE__UrlVisit","UrlVisit"]                 |
==> | <null>                                | <null>               | ["File","__TYPE__File"]                         |
==> | <null>                                | <null>               | ["__TYPE__UrlVisit","UrlVisit"]                 |
==> | <null>                                | <null>               | ["__TYPE__UrlVisit","UrlVisit"]                 |
==> | "Blog software"                       | <null>               | ["DocumentCategory","__TYPE__DocumentCategory"] |
==> | <null>                                | <null>               | ["File","__TYPE__File"]                         |
==> | "WordPress"                           | <null>               | ["DocumentCategory","__TYPE__DocumentCategory"] |
==> | "Content management systems"          | <null>               | ["DocumentCategory","__TYPE__DocumentCategory"] |
==> | <null>                                | "WEB_PAGE"           | ["Document","__TYPE__Document"]                 |
==> | <null>                                | "WEB_PAGE"           | ["Document","__TYPE__Document"]                 |
==> | <null>                                | <null>               | ["__TYPE__UrlVisit","UrlVisit"]                 |
==> | <null>                                | <null>               | ["ScreenCapture","__TYPE__ScreenCapture"]       |
==> | <null>                                | "WEB_PAGE"           | ["Document","__TYPE__Document"]                 |
==> | <null>                                | <null>               | ["__TYPE__UrlVisit","UrlVisit"]                 |
==> | <null>                                | <null>               | ["ScreenCapture","__TYPE__ScreenCapture"]       |
==> | <null>                                | "WEB_PAGE"           | ["Document","__TYPE__Document"]                 |
==> | <null>                                | <null>               | ["__TYPE__UrlVisit","UrlVisit"]                 |
==> | <null>                                | "WEB_PAGE"           | ["Document","__TYPE__Document"]                 |
==> | "Beers"                               | <null>               | ["DocumentCategory","__TYPE__DocumentCategory"] |
==> | <null>                                | <null>               | ["__TYPE__UrlVisit","UrlVisit"]                 |
==> | "http://people.kmi.open.ac.uk/john/"  | "HOME_PAGE"          | ["__TYPE__Entity","Entity"]                     |
==> | "OPEN UNIVERSITY"                     | "ORGANIZATION"       | ["__TYPE__Entity","Entity"]                     |
```

I used the index name 'entity_name_ft' only in the class EntityNode but as you can see above the Cypher query also returns nodes of type Document, DocumentCategory, UrlVisits etc...

I'm doing the inserts only through SDN and I don't manually index nodes in the Cypher console.

Has anyone encountered this kind of behavior?
Someone please explain this, please.

Comment: What version of SDN are you using?

Comment: I was using 3.0.0.RC1 (moved to 3.0.0.RELEASE recently)

Comment: Do you get the same result with `start n=node:entity_name_ft('name:*') return n.name, n.type, labels(n);`?

Comment: Well, in the meantime I manually ran some update scripts to correct the labeling. Also, like said previously, I moved to 3.0.0.RELEASE. I now, get the right results.